# Control color in r plot

Tags: r, plot, vegan

The output of nestednodf, a function of package vegan, can be easily plotted. I'd like to highlight selected rows in a different color but I don't know how to specify it in a single plot. Say that I want rows 1,3 and 5 in blue and rows 2 and 4 in red (default color). This code allows to overlap a second plot with rows 1,3,5 in blue but doesn't insert the selected rows in the first one:

```
library(vegan)
df=data.frame(a=c(0,1,1,1,0), b=c(1,0,0,0,1), c=c(1,1,1,1,0), d=c(1,0,1,0,1), e=c(0,0,0,1,1))
plot(nestednodf(df))
plot(nestednodf(df[c(1,3,5),]), col='blue', add=T)
```

Is there any way to control row color? Something like this:

```
plot(nestednodf(df), row.col=c('blue', '', 'blue', '', 'blue'))
```

Comment: Could you clarify " but doesn't insert the selected rows in the first one"?

Comment: The second plot overlaps the first one, and although it plots my selected rows, doesn't obviously put them in the desired order on the first plot, it simply plots the rows that I specified over the first plot. What I wanted was to color different rows with different colors on the first plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the source of the function by entering `vegan:::plot.nestednodf`. There's not really an opportunity two tweak row colors. However you can see the function is pretty simple so you can write your own version

```
myplot <- function (x, col = "red", names = FALSE, ...) 
{
    z <- x$comm
    z <- t(z[nrow(z):1, ])

    if (length(col) == 1) 
        col <- c(NA, col)
    else if ( length(col)>1) {
        z <- z*((col(z)-1)%%2+1)
    }
    image(z, axes = FALSE, col = col, ...)
    box()
    if (length(names) == 1) 
        names <- rep(names, 2)
    if (names[1]) {
        axis(2, at = seq(1, 0, len = ncol(z)), labels = rev(colnames(z)), 
            las = 2, ...)
    }
    if (names[2]) {
        axis(3, at = seq(0, 1, len = nrow(z)), labels = rownames(z), 
            las = 2, ...)
    }
}
```

Here I just added a line to change the colors to be alternating between the values specified. Compare

```
plot(nestednodf(df))
myplot(nestednodf(df), col=c(NA,'red','blue'))
```

[image]

Note that I pass three colors because the first is used for the "0" values in the matrix